# KDE is broken after update today to Debian Testing/Bullseye

Tags: debian, kde

I updated my Debian Testing today to Plasma version 4:5.14.5.1 and then tried standby mode. As I started the PC again (it was seemingly properly shutdown) the system tray icons vanished and the search with Alt+Space did only show contacts. Also when rightclicking on a widget there is no context menu anymore. I can't use my PC normally now anymore, what happend? I tried restarting multiple times already but everything stays the same.

after the update:

```
Versions of packages plasma-workspace depends on:
ii  dbus-user-session [default-dbus-session-bus]  1.12.16-1
ii  dbus-x11 [dbus-session-bus]                   1.12.16-1
ii  drkonqi                                       5.14.5-1
ii  frameworkintegration                          5.62.0-1
ii  gdb-minimal [gdb]                             8.3-1
ii  iso-codes                                     4.3-1
ii  kactivitymanagerd                             5.14.5-1
ii  kded5                                         5.62.0-1
ii  kinit                                         5.62.0-1
ii  kio                                           5.62.1-1
ii  kpackagetool5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  kwin-common                                   4:5.14.5-1
ii  libappstreamqt2                               0.12.9-1
ii  libc6                                         2.29-2
ii  libcolorcorrect5                              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libgcc1                                       1:9.2.1-8
ii  libgps23                                      3.17-7
ii  libice6                                       2:1.0.9-2
ii  libkf5activities5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5authcore5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5baloo5                                  5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5bookmarks5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5calendarevents5                         5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5completion5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5config-bin                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configcore5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configgui5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5configwidgets5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5coreaddons5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5crash5                                  5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5dbusaddons5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5declarative5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5globalaccel-bin                         5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5globalaccel5                            5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5guiaddons5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5holidays5                               1:5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5i18n5                                   5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5iconthemes5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5idletime5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5itemviews5                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5jobwidgets5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5js5                                     5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5jsembed5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5kdelibs4support5                        5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5kiocore5                                5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiofilewidgets5                         5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiogui5                                 5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5kiowidgets5                             5.62.1-1
ii  libkf5networkmanagerqt6                       5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5newstuff5                               5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5notifications5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5notifyconfig5                           5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5package5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5plasma5                                 5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5plasmaquick5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5prison5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5quickaddons5                            5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5runner5                                 5.54.0-1
ii  libkf5service-bin                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5service5                                5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5solid5                                  5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5texteditor5                             5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5textwidgets5                            5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5wallet-bin                              5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5wallet5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5waylandclient5                          4:5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5widgetsaddons5                          5.62.0-1
ii  libkf5windowsystem5                           5.62.0-2
ii  libkf5xmlgui5                                 5.62.0-1
ii  libkscreenlocker5                             5.14.5-1
ii  libksgrd7                                     4:5.14.5-1
ii  libkworkspace5-5                              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libphonon4qt5-4                               4:4.10.3-3
ii  libplasma-geolocation-interface5              4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libprocesscore7                               4:5.14.5-1
ii  libprocessui7                                 4:5.14.5-1
ii  libqalculate20                                2.8.2-1+b1
ii  libqt5core5a                                  5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5dbus5                                   5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5gui5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5network5                                5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5qml5                                    5.11.3-4
ii  libqt5quick5                                  5.11.3-4
ii  libqt5sql5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5widgets5                                5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libqt5x11extras5                              5.11.3-2
ii  libqt5xml5                                    5.11.3+dfsg1-4
ii  libsm6                                        2:1.2.3-1
ii  libstdc++6                                    9.2.1-8
ii  libtaskmanager6                               4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libweather-ion7                               4:5.14.5.1-2
ii  libx11-6                                      2:1.6.8-1
ii  libxcb-composite0                             1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-damage0                                1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-image0                                 0.4.0-1+b2
ii  libxcb-randr0                                 1.13.1-2
ii  libxcb-util0                                  0.3.8-3+b2
ii  libxcb1                                       1.13.1-2
ii  libxfixes3                                    1:5.0.3-1
ii  libxrender1                                   1:0.9.10-1
ii  libxtst6                                      2:1.2.3-1
ii  milou                                         4:5.14.5-1
ii  phonon4qt5                                    4:4.10.3-3
ii  plasma-framework                              5.54.0-1
ii  plasma-integration                            5.14.5-1
ii  qdbus-qt5                                     5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-org-kde-draganddrop                5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kcoreaddons                5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kholidays                  1:5.62.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrols             5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kquickcontrolsaddons       5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem              5.54.0-1
ii  qml-module-org-kde-solid                      5.62.0-2
ii  qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel            5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects                 5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtqml-models2                      5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick-controls                   5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtquick-dialogs                    5.11.3-2
ii  qml-module-qtquick-layouts                    5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick-window2                    5.11.3-4
ii  qml-module-qtquick2                           5.11.3-4
ii  udisks2                                       2.8.4-1
ii  x11-utils                                     7.7+4
ii  x11-xserver-utils                             7.7+8
ii  zlib1g                                        1:1.2.11.dfsg-1+b1

Versions of packages plasma-workspace recommends:
ii  kde-cli-tools    4:5.14.5-1
ii  kio-extras       4:19.08.1-1
ii  ksysguardd       4:5.14.5-1
ii  libpam-kwallet5  5.14.5-1
ii  powerdevil       4:5.14.5-1
```

If you need more information feel free to ask in a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it happened to me too.

I returned to the **buster**:

/etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://alcateia.ufscar.br/debian/ buster main non-free contrib
```

So, I made this:

```
sudo apt purge kde* plasma* tasksel*
sudo apt autoremove --purge
sudo apt install tasksel
sudo apt install task-kde-desktop task-desktop task-print-server task-ssh-server
```

I got back to **buster** while the bug doesn't has a fix.

I hope this help you

Answer (score 2):

it happened to me too.

Now in unstable you can find plasma-workspace 4:5.14.5.1-3 Installing it solved the problem for me.

Comment: its fixed for me with testing by now